# How should "gimme-code" questions be flagged?

Tags: discussion, homework

The main question in question is:

[Homework Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35675606/3000206)

But this certainly isn't the first "gimme-code"/do-my-homework-for-me question (and likely won't be the last).

How should these be flagged? In the first flag screen, "off-topic" seemed like the best option (although in retrospect, "low-quality" would have worked too), but then the "because..." screen didn't show any seemingly relevant reasons.

How should these questions be flagged?

Comment: After down voting for an not useful questio you close vote/flag as either *Unclear what you're asking* or *Too broad*, both will work. The first one has the benefit of linking to How to Ask in the help centre. The second one has the benefit of explaining in post notice to add details. Flagging as low quality is not the correct option. Reserve that for gibberish.

Comment: @rene The problem is, the question was neither "too broad" or "unclear". He spelled out a homework question. It was *very* specific, and not at all unclear what he was asking. Unless he just forgot to ask the question, he wanted people to do his homework for him. That's why I picked "off-topic".

Comment: It is too broad if we need to do all the work which is the case for that question. It isn't off-topic, unless you went for the lacks an MCVE option. That might be an option but I hardly ever use it on cases like you presented because those OP's need more guidance then just some debug/MCVE tips.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to post this on the Stack Overflow Meta. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question is a 'gimme the code' question, which is clear, not too broad and actually answerable, the only thing you can do is downvote it, since it doesn't show any effort.

Flagging doesn't make sense, since it isn't a low quality question.

Closing is an option sometimes with these kind of 'gimme the code' questions, as too broad or unclear, whatever is applicable in that situation. Sometimes these questions have a duplicate and it is okay to close it as such.

Usually the ton of downvotes are enough to get someone question banned or put on a rate limit. That will prevent questions like that to come in from that user again.